# Autocomplete does not work in MySQL and there is no my.cnf file anywhere

Tags: autocomplete, mysql-workbench

I tried to look for the answer but I really can't find a solution to what I thought it was something simple (I know, how naive of me). So, basically the only thing I want is for the autocomplete in MySQL to work not only when typing commands (i.e. SELECT, WHERE, etc.), but also (and most importantly) when typing the name of a column, which right now, is not working. I don't have a my.cnf file anywhere that I can find. I do see in the "Manage Server Connections" window under the System Profile that the configuration file should be /etc/my.cnf, but again, there is no such file anywhere in this computer. I already spent a bunch of time trying to figure this out and had not choice but to post here. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: Auto-complete is not a feature of mysql, it is a feature of the client you use to connect to it. my.cnf is a config file for mysql, it has nothing to do with any code completion features of the client.

Comment: Sorry, I should have maybe said MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I updated to version MySQL Workbench 8.025 (latest as of today) and it worked. I should have done this from the beginning. Now it is working.